# Are EC2 security group changes effective immediately for running instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance running, and it belongs to a security group. If I add a new allowed connection to that security group through AWS Management Console, **should that change be effective immediately**? Or perhaps only after restart of the instance?

In my case, I'm trying to allow access to PostgreSQL's default port (tcp 5432 5432 0.0.0.0/0), and I'm not sure if it's the EC2 firewall or PostgreSQL's settings that are refusing the connection.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Seems like **yes** (quoting [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules)):

> You can modify rules for a group at
>   any time. **The new rules are
>   automatically enforced for all running
>   instances** and instances launched in
>   the future.

A simple test of disallowing access to a certain (previously accessible) port also confirmed this.

Comment: I tested this and it's true.

Comment: However when allowing access to a previously disallowed resource it can take up to a minute or two before the new policy becomes effective and access is granted.

Comment: I've had several instances where both allowing and disallowing have taken over 30 seconds to propagate. So instant is definitely not true. Pretty fast though... but be patient for a minute or two before drawing conclusions :)

Comment: Link posted in the answer seems broken as on today. Can someone correct it please?

Answer (score 2):

The 'listen_addresses' directive on postgresql.conf defaults to 127.0.0.1 only. 
It should be changed to listen_addresses = '*' to accept connections from 0.0.0.0/0